# im unable to package get the package "english words" in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, package

I'm unable to get the required package English_words.
under dependencies I added English_words: ^3.1.5

screenshot of "pubspec.yaml" file with execution:

[image]

**Edit:** Issue resolved, importing package worked fine. The full code is also given in the flutter docs.

Comment: Why are you saying you cannot get? I see now error. `exit code 0` means all worked fine. Only the `+` sign on the left seems wired to me.

Comment: What's the `+` for at the beginning of the line `+  english words: ^3.1.5`?

Comment: Yes i think + symbol is issue.

Comment: Probably following the codelab, which is indicating via a diff that english_words should be added to the pubspec.  Yes, it's found on the page at https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/codelab#step-2-use-an-external-package (turned this comment into an answer...)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are following the tutorial at https://flutter.io/docs/get-started/codelab#step-2-use-an-external-package ... the "+" in front of `english_words` there is an indicator of a diff. You should add that line, but leave off the +.

Answer (score 0):

I found error in pubspec.yaml file as shown in your screenshot. You need to add **english_words: ^3.1.5** to **dev_dependencies** rather than in **dependencies**. Actual code snippet will be:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

Then click on **Package get (shown in Android Studio)** option to add above dependency for the project. You can also do the same using command(in project stucture):

```
flutter packages get
```